# What is the meaning of ${arg##/*/} and {} \; in shell scripting

Tags: shell, sh

Please find the code below for displaying the directories in the current folder.

1. What is the meaning of `${arg##/*/}` in shell scripting. (Both `arg#*` and `arg##/*/` gives the same output. )
2. What is the meaning of `{} \;` in for loop statement.

```
for arg in `find . -type d -exec ls -d {} \;`
do
  echo "Output 1" ${arg##/*/}
  echo "Output 2" ${arg#*}
done
```

Comment: You should add backticks around code segments (see my edits) or you get problems with the formatting (including undisplayed characters)

Comment: `${arg#}*` would only match `${arg##/*/}` if arg did not start with a `/` and/or contain at least 2 `/` (i.e. if `/*/` was unmatched in the string)

Comment: You've obviously never gotten frustrated with a shell script that wouldn't work, at 3 in the morning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding to @JoSo's helpful answer:

`${arg#*}` is a *fundamentally pointless* expansion, as its result is always identical to `$arg` itself, since it strips the *shortest* prefix matching *any* character (`*`) and the shortest prefix matching any character is the empty string.

`${arg##/*/}` - stripping the *longest* prefix matching pattern `/*/` - is *useless in this context*, because the output paths will be `./`-prefixed due to use of `find .`, so there will be no prefix starting with `/`. By contrast, `${arg##*/}` will work and strip the parent path (leaving the folder-name component only).

Aside from it being [ill-advised to parse command output in a `for` loop](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), as @JoSo points out,
the `find` command in the OP is overly complicated and inefficient
(as an aside, just to clarify, the `find` command lists all folders in the current folder's *subtree*, not just immediate subfolders):

```
find . -type d -exec ls -d {} \;
```

can be simplified to:

```
find . -type d
```

The two commands do the same: `-exec ls -d {} \;` simply does what `find` does by default anyway (an implied `-print`).

If we put it all together, we get:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d | while read -r arg
do
  echo "Folder name: ${arg##*/}"
  echo "Parent path: ${arg%/*}"
done
```

Note that I've used `${arg%/*}` as the second output item, which strips the shortest *suffix* matching `/*` and thus returns the *parent* path; furthermore, I've added `-mindepth 1` so that `find` doesn't also match `.`

@JoSo, in a comment, demonstrates a solution that's both simpler and more efficient; it uses `-exec` to process a shell command in-line and `+` to pass as many paths as possible at once:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec /bin/sh -c \
  'for arg; do echo "Folder name: ${arg##*/}"; echo "Parent: ${arg%/*}"; done' \
  -- {} +
```

Finally, if you have GNU `find`, things get even easier, as you can take advantage of the `-printf` primary, which supports placeholders for things like filenames and parent paths:

```
find . -type d -printf 'Folder name: %f\nParen path: %h\n'
```

---

Here's a **bash-only solution based on globbing (pathname expansion)**, courtesy of @Adrian Frühwirth:

**Caveat**: This requires `bash 4+`, with the shell option `globstar` turned ON (`shopt -s globstar`) - it is OFF by default.

```
shopt -s globstar # bash 4+ only: turn on support for ** 
for arg in **/  # process all directories in the entire subtree
do
  echo "Folder name: $(basename "$arg")"
  echo "Parent path: $(dirname "$arg")"
done
```

Note that I'm using `basename` and `dirname` here for parsing, as they conveniently ignore the terminating `/` that the glob `**/` invariably adds to its matches.

---

Afterthought re processing `find`'s output in a `while` loop: on the off chance that your filenames contain embedded `\n` chars, you can parse as follows, using a null char. to separate items (see comments for why `-d $'\0'` rather than `-d ''` is used):

```
find . -type d -print0 | while read -d $'\0' -r arg; ...
```

Comment: `-d $'\0'` doesn't really exist. Although `read` is builtin, it has `argv` (C language) semantics for arguments passing (just like external programs, which is a good thing). C strings can't have NUL characters. It's really the same as `-d ''` (A string of length zero) which happens to work just because of the particular bash implementation.

Comment: What you really want (if at all) is `find -type d -exec /bin/sh -c 'arg=$1; echo "Folder: ${arg##*/}"; echo "Parent: ${arg##%/*}"' -- {} \;'` which is quite complicated

Comment: Alternatively, `find -type d -exec /bin/sh -c 'for arg in "$@"; do echo "Folder: ${arg##*/}"; echo Parent: ${arg##%/*}; done"' -- {} +`

Comment: @JoSo: Thanks for the streamlined `find` commands; I've incorporated the latter in my answer; note that I added `.` as the path argument, as some `find` implementations (e.g., on OSX) do require an explicit one. I've also added a GNU `find` solution using `-printf` that's even simpler.

Comment: @JoSo: Re `-d $'\0'`: thanks for the explanation - did not know that. I conclude that it's still OK to use it, though: As long as bash argument parsing and its builtins use NUL characters to terminate strings, the command will still work for the reasons you state; should that ever change, the command should continue to work, as `find`'s output is effectively NUL-separated when used with `-print0`.

Comment: (I've changed the `$'\0'` to `''` as that's what it really is: A zero-length nul-terminated string)

Comment: @JoSo: Let me first say that your edit is fine for all intents and purposes - it's unlikely that bash's string-handling internals will change; that said, `-d $'\0'` strikes me as more future-proof, at least hypothetically; the downside is that it suggests a capability that isn't actually there currently due to an implementation choice (which is probably what prompted your edit). But I think we've now covered all angles and can let sleeping NULs lie.

Comment: Your arguing is very sound. I feel guilty of imposing my (sometimes maybe too) strong feelings on your answer :(. I've undone my edit. Thanks for the discussion :-)

Comment: +1, you might want to incorporate `for dir in */; do [...]` and `for dir in */**/; do [...]` into your great answer for non-`find` solutions (the trailing slash tells the shell to only expand directories).

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth: Thanks for that - didn't know the terminating-`/` trick - very handy. Thank you also for `**` (requires shell option `globstar` set and thus `bash >=4`): I'll incorporate it into the answer (but not the `*/`, solution, as the answer is about matching in the _entire subtree_).

Answer (score 2):

1. `${arg##/*/}` is an application of "parameter expansion". (Search for this term in your shell's manual, e.g. type `man bash` in a linux shell). It expands to `arg` without the longest prefix of arg that matches `/*/` as a glob pattern. E.g. if `arg` is `/foo/bar/doo`, it expands to `doo`.
2. That's bad shell code (similar to item #1 on [Bash Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)). The `{} \;` has not so much to do with shell, but more with the arguments that the `find` command expects to an `-exec` subcommand. The `{}` is replaced with the current filename, e.g. this results in `find` executing the command `ls -d FILENAME` with FILENAME replaced by each file it found. The `\;` serves as a terminator of the `-exec` argument. See the manual page of `find`, e.g. type `man find` on a linux shell, and look for the string `-exec` there to find the description.